# Executing SP in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

First of all I am new in Oracle stored procedures so I am not used to compiling them.

I have tried to compile the stored procedure below but got exception.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
o_res_code NUMBER;
o_res_msg VARCHAR2(500);
o_curr_blnc NUMBER;
o_prev_blnc NUMBER;
BEGIN
execute SP_SC_REDEEM ('82201026551015', 1, '4739',45478,systimestamp, systimestamp,7875,82227357776962, 1.1, 1.1,:o_curr_blnc, :o_prev_blnc, :o_res_code, :o_res_msg);
END;
```

EXCEPTION:

```
Bind Variable "o_curr_blnc" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed
```

Can someone please correct me?

Comment: Remove execute from the code. You do not need them in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared local variables so you don't need the colons to reference them. Also, `execute` is not needed in a PL/SQL block.

```
DECLARE
    o_res_code NUMBER;
    o_res_msg VARCHAR2(500);
    o_curr_blnc NUMBER;
    o_prev_blnc NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SP_SC_REDEEM ('82201026551015', 1, '4739',45478
       ,systimestamp, systimestamp,7875,82227357776962, 1.1, 1.1
       ,o_curr_blnc, o_prev_blnc, o_res_code, o_res_msg);
END;
```